# No me funciona la propiedad [toggleMask]="true"

Tags: angular, primeng

Deseo que se muestre el ojo para ocultar o mostrar la contraseña, según la documentación oficial la propiedad es [toggleMask]="true" pero no me funciona.

Esto es lo que deseo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero se me muestra así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del componente

```
<input pPassword type="password" formControlName="contraDlg" [feedback]="false" [toggleMask]="true"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157143/togglemask-in-primeng-password-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use el selector de componentes en lugar de la directiva, ya que la directiva no contiene toggleMask( Ver aquí ) donde sí lo hace el componente.

Asegúrate de importarPasswordModule

```
import { PasswordModule } from "primeng/password";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    PasswordModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

y usarlo así

```
<p-password [toggleMask]="true"></p-password> //Works
```

Ejemplo de Stackblitz

Por cierto, la `pPassworddirectiva` tiene `showPassword @Input` que se puede usar para alternar la visualización de la contraseña